# Bigger map annotation callouts in iPad

Tags: ipad

In iPad photos application, under "Places", you can see a map of where the photos are taken. When the user taps an annotation, a callout appears showing a stack of photos for that place. How can we achieve the same effect (bigger annotation callout with custom information) in our own iPad applications?

Do we have to create a custom MKAnnotationView class to do it or is it possible to do it using built-in MKPinAnnotationView class?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to roll your own annotation view. The default `MKAnnotationView` (and `MKPinAnnotationView`) callout doesn't give you a whole lot of room for customization.